# 404 Not Shown For Custom Module - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, routes

In a `hook_menu()` implementation, I am defining a route for login.

```
function my_account_menu() {
  $items['login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Customer Login',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('my_account_login_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

However, if I try accessing login/asdfdsa, it still loads the login page, instead of showing a 404 error.

Is there an error on the code I wrote, or in the module?

Comment: Believe it or not, that’s the expected behaviour. To the best of my knowledge it’s never been addressed. It’s been raised as an issue plenty of times, but never solved as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the expected behavior, and it's described in the documentation for [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x), even it  could not be clear, at a quick read.

> #### Callback Functions
>
> The definition for each path may include a page callback function,
>   which is invoked when the registered path is requested. If there is no
>   other registered path that fits the requested path better, any further
>   path components are passed to the callback function. For example, your
>   module could register path 'abc/def':
>
> ```
> function mymodule_menu() {
>   $items['abc/def'] = array(
>     'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
>   );
>   return $items;
> }
>
> function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> When path 'abc/def' is requested, no further path components are in
>   the request, and no additional arguments are passed to the callback
>   function (so `$ghi` and `$jkl` would take the default values as
>   defined in the function signature). When 'abc/def/123/foo' is
>   requested, `$ghi` will be '123' and `$jkl` will be 'foo'. Note that
>   this automatic passing of optional path arguments applies only to page
>   and theme callback functions.

This means that, for example with login/asdfdsa, Drupal will first check if there are modules that handle that path. If there aren't modules handling that path, Drupal will check if there are modules handling every path matching login/*; if there aren't modules for those paths, Drupal will check if there are modules that handle login. In your case, that is your module. (I left out how Drupal handles the path aliases, as in this case isn't relevant.)

That happens also for other paths, for example node/1. If you have a node whose ID is 1, /node/1 shows it. If you try to access a path like, for example, /node/1/sdfgrgjpqwd432az, you will still see that node. (*sdfgrgjpqwd432az* is just a random string, to be sure I am not using a path for which a module defines a page callback.)

Comment: I definitely read the documentation a bit too quickly. Thank you for this thorough explanation.

Comment: I know people that have been using Drupal for years and didn't notice that. Most people would tell you that a path like abc/def/123/foo is handled by your module if it defines a route like abc/def/%/%, which isn't true.